# Why am I not getting static libraries while getting shared libraries built using ndk-build?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am trying to generate **rn-noise** `static libraries`. So far, I am able to generate `Shared Libraries`. What I am unable to understand is why am I not getting static libraries? Please have a look:

---

### Shared Library

[image: ndk-build while using ndk-bundle]

[image: .so files generated]

---

### Static Library

Now if I build Static libraries then I get the following things:
[image: ndk-build while using ndk-bundle]

[image: No Static Files generated]

My **Android.mk** is as following:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE:= rnnoise

RNN_SOURCES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/celt_lpc.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/denoise.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/kiss_fft.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/pitch.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/rnn.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/rnn_data.c \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/rnn_reader.c \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(RNN_SOURCES) \
    com_example_rnnoise_Rnnoise.c

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/include/ \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/rnnoise-master/src/

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

What is the solution to this problem? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: From what I can see, the static library is being built. It's just not getting packaged into your APK, because normally that's not something one would do. Normally one would only build static libraries for the purpose of linking shared libraries against them at build-time. And the only libraries you'd package into your APK would be the shared libraries.

Comment: @Michael thank you very much. Now it's clear to me that the package will only contain .so files rather than .a files. Am I correct?